# Count number of customers in each Distinct city from customer table in sql

Tags: mysql, sql, xampp

My database has a table named `customer` with data in the following columns: `id`, `first_name`, `last_name`, and `city`.

Like this:

[image]

Now I need a table with the number of `customers` in each Distinct `city`. what should the `SQL` query for it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use COUNT aggregate function -

```
SELECT city, COUNT(ID)
  FROM customer
 GROUP BY city;
```